# Passar imagem para HTML através de ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Possuo uma imagem em um array de bytes, e preciso inseri-la na *view*.

Há alguma maneira de eu fazer isto através de `ViewBag`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, várias.

A que eu acho mais interessante é converter este *array* de bytes numa `string` em Base64.

```
var byteArray = GerarByteArray();
string strBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);

var imgSrc = $"data:image/png;base64,{strBase64}";

ViewBag.Base64Image = imgSrc;
```

Na view, você usaria algo como

```
<img src="@ViewBag.Base64Image />
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7wLBpH)

---

Demonstração de imagem em Base64.

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
```

Comment: "var imgSrc = $"data:image/png;base64,{base64 }";", esta parte seria para que?

Comment: A tag `img` precisa deste prefixo (`data:image/png;base64,`) para "saber" que a imagem é uma string em Base64 e não um caminho. O código serve para concatenar a string em base64 junto com este prefixo.

Comment: ah sim, entendi, muito obrigado, funcionou :D